# Why time cost is 0 seconds after call std::async?

Tags: c++

See the following code.

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    std::future<int> future = std::async(std::launch::deferred, [](){ 
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
            return 100;  
        }); 
    std::cout << "waiting...\n";

    clock_t start = clock();
    std::future_status status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
    std::cout << "result is " << future.get() << std::endl;
    clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout<<"Time Cost : "<< (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<" seconds."<< std::endl;
}
```

It's very confusing about the execution result. Yep, the main thread will wait for only 5 seconds around and then print "100". But why "Time Cost" shows 0? The test environment is Cygwin with g++ 4.9.3. 
Then I tested it in VS2013. The result is 25 seocnds. Strange!

Comment: Well your current code doesn't even compile, a small error, but obviously this isn't your real test. Please provide your real test.

Comment: Why are you using legacy clock_t in C++14 application?

Comment: I compiled it (fixing the spelling of deferred) and the output shows around 5 seconds for me.

Comment: @BoBTFish, My test environment is Cygwin. with g++ 4.9.3. My command is "g++ 1.cpp -std=c++11". It can pass.

Comment: @SergeyA, what's your suggestion to replace clock_t?

Comment: @BrianWalker, what's your environment?

Comment: @Finix, I'd suggest `std::chrono::steady_clock`. But since you've said 'cygwin'...

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_clock.htm)? It has the same bug. That's because it assigns a `double` to a `clock_t`. You are not assigning a `double` to a `clock_t` in your real code, are you?

Comment: @Fozi, no one is assigning a double to a clock_t. You seem to be confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clock()` returns processor time spent. It doesn't have **any** guarantee of advancement whatsoever. If your CPU sleeps, the value returned by it will not be advanced. To measure intervals properly, use clocks from `std::chrono`, for example, `std::chrono::steady_clock`.

Comment: After I changed the program to use std::chrono::steady_clock, Cygwin can show "Time Cost" as 5 seconds. And the real wait time is indeed 5 seconds. However, VS2013 still shows 25 seconds, and the real wait time is also 25 seconds. Not sure why VS2013 looks bad.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't show 0 on my machine but a very small value : 0;000156s. But as it measures processor time and your main thread does not consume any cpu (wait is not an active loop), the result is almost 0.

Comment: I test it in VS2013, the result is 25 seconds around. But in Cygwin with g++, it is 0 second. Why are they different?

Comment: wait_for support seems to be broken, wait_for should wait until delay or result delivery, in your case 5 seconds!